# Documentation for source code of wget

Tags: documentation, wget

I downloaded the source code of `wget` from http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/wget/ (file wget-1.14.tar.gz). Is there any place where I can read to understand the whole structure of the source code? I can't find any such file in what I downloaded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A good place to start seems to be [Getting Started With the Wget Program Source Code](http://wget.addictivecode.org/NavigatingTheSource) from the wiki for GNU wget.